# How to relevel with mixedsort with pipes?

Tags: r, dplyr

How do you relevel a factor with dplyr and mixedsort in the same pipe?

```
df %>%
     relevel(.$var, mixedsort(levels(.$var)))
```

Results in error message "'relevel' only for (unordered) factors" even though var is a factor. I have also tried using the magrittr pipe and the `relevel(var, mixedsort(levels(var)))` but to no avail.

I guess this could all be done by saving mixedsort(levels(var)) and then calling it from within the relevel function but I would like to do it all in one relevel call if possible.

Comment: wrap with `{}` around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can wrap with `{}`, however, the `relevel` `ref` takes only a single element

```
library(dplyr)
library(gtools)
iris %>% 
     {relevel(.$Species, mixedsort(levels(.$Species))[1])}
```

Or change the order of levels, apply `factor`

```
iris %>%
     {factor(.$Species, levels = mixedsort(levels(.$Species)))}
```

If we want to reorder, another option is `fct_relevel`

```
library(forcats)
iris %>%
    {fct_relevel(.$Species, mixedsort(levels(.$Species)))}
```

---

Or as we are using `dplyr`, do that in `mutate` or `transmute` and then `pull` (`transmute` if only a single column is required and then want to `pull` as a `vector)

```
iris %>%
   transmute(Species = factor(Species, levels = mixedsort(levels(Species)))) %>%
   pull(Species)
```

If we need the full set of columns, use `mutate`

```
iris1 <- iris %>%
   mutate(Species = factor(Species, levels = mixedsort(levels(Species))))
```

Comment: Is there a pipe-supported way to reorder all levels?

Comment: @TeaTree you can use `fct_relevel` or just use `factor(.$Species, levels = mixedsort(levels(.$Species)))`

Comment: @TeaTree in the example with `iris`, the mixedsort is not applicable, but I am just showing a reproducible example

Comment: I think I might have accepted too early. How would I make sure to keep all other columns in the dataset?

Comment: @TeaTree that is the reason I was thinking why you need to do `.$`, instead use `mutate`